# JSON loses attributes when deserializing

Tags: java, gson

The client passes a JSON string to a server, and a server deserializes the string into an Object,like this:

```
    @PostMapping("/web/UploadVideo")
    @ApiOperation("UploadVideo")
    public Result uploadVideoWB(HttpServletRequest request,
                                @RequestParam("sourceFile") MultipartFile sourceFile,
                                @RequestParam("videoBean") String videoBean) {
        Object object = request.getSession().getAttribute("UserId");
        if (object == null) {
            System.out.println("userId is null");
            return new Result(false, "UserId is null", null, null);
        } else {
            System.out.println("1. " + videoBean);
            VideoBean video = new Gson().fromJson(videoBean, VideoBean.class);
            video.setVideoUser((String) object);
            System.out.println("2. " + new Gson().toJson(video));
            return videoService.uploadVideo(sourceFile, new Gson().toJson(video));
        }
    }
```

The console output is like this:
format them：

```
{
    "objectId": "e3da789b-c514-2a55-c5f8-1882ae4863c9", 
    "videoId": "3be5e2c3-edf5-66d9-3c93-e3b4d2cdc35c", 
    "sha1": "92e343d96ca29ddf3b631f52f39e771fabff1c97", 
    "duration": 0, 
    "fileCategory": "bbe0e1d4c9bc4e9390871a52cd641c42", 
    "originalFileName": "WeChat_20211124011655.mp4", 
    "sourceFileName": "e1d26875-cd88-423d-568b-86b2cfeee7fc.mp4", 
    "coverFileName": "db0bc7a4-f900-0483-13c6-5d0227d10e27.png", 
    "thumbnailFileName": "5a34eb29-eaa2-a507-baab-97951c06926c.png", 
    "blurFileName": "17dceb9c-0c88-dcd1-cb4d-96e3c4f9a814.png", 
    "createTime": 1637692690492, 
    "videoUser": "", 
    "videoStatus": 1
}

{
    "objectId": "e3da789b-c514-2a55-c5f8-1882ae4863c9", 
    "videoId": "3be5e2c3-edf5-66d9-3c93-e3b4d2cdc35c", 
    "sha1": "92e343d96ca29ddf3b631f52f39e771fabff1c97", 
    "duration": 0, 
    "fileCategory": "bbe0e1d4c9bc4e9390871a52cd641c42", 
    "sourceFileName": "e1d26875-cd88-423d-568b-86b2cfeee7fc.mp4", 
    "coverFileName": "db0bc7a4-f900-0483-13c6-5d0227d10e27.png", 
    "thumbnailFileName": "5a34eb29-eaa2-a507-baab-97951c06926c.png", 
    "blurFileName": "17dceb9c-0c88-dcd1-cb4d-96e3c4f9a814.png", 
    "videoUser": "84f6e0d8d94348ccab981e364661a419", 
    "videoStatus": 1, 
    "createTime": 1637692690492
}
```

You can see that the **originalFileName** attribute is gone! ! !

VideoBean.class：

```
public class VideoBean {
    private String objectId;
    private String videoId;
    private String sha1;
    private long duration;
    private String fileCategory;
    private String originalFilename;
    private String sourceFileName;
    private String coverFileName;
    private String thumbnailFileName;
    private String blurFileName;
    private String videoUser;
    private int videoStatus;
    private long createTime;

    getter/setter ...
}
```

Why?

What should I do to make deserialization normal?

Comment: You have typo in field name. Change `private String originalFilename` to `private String originalFileName` with capital N for Name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `VideoBean` is wrong (`originalFilename` in your class vs. `originalFileName` in your JSON, mind the lowercase `n` in `name`). Use the following one:

```java
public class VideoBean {
    private String objectId;
    private String videoId;
    private String sha1;
    private long duration;
    private String fileCategory;
    private String originalFileName;
    private String sourceFileName;
    private String coverFileName;
    private String thumbnailFileName;
    private String blurFileName;
    private String videoUser;
    private int videoStatus;
    private long createTime;

    getter/setter ...
}
```

Comment: OMG，This error is really too low-level, I wasted an hour on this question, thank you so much

Comment: Your answer is too fast, I won’t be able to accept the answer after 5 minutes

Comment: Please avoid answering such questions (caused by typos). They don't help anyone else. Instead, drop a comment if you've spotted the typo and flag/vote to close instead. Deletion can't happen (automatically) if the post is answered.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I will place a comment instead in the future.